# Why does the string input value "male" != "male" return true when using .lower in python?

Tags: python

I am trying to compare an input value for error handling but my if statement returns true the first time then false the second time. I am checking if the input value is not equal to "male" or "female".

Method 1:

```
def init_greeating(self):
        gender = input("Enter your gender\n")
        gender = gender.lower()
        if(gender != "male" or gender != "female"):
            gender = input("I do not know that gender. Try again ")
        return
```

Output

```
Enter your gender 
male
I do not know that gender. Try again
male
How excellent! Are you a CS Major?
```

Method 2

```
def init_greeating(self):
        gender = input("Enter your gender\n")
        gender = gender.lower()  

        if gender != "male":
            gender = input("I do not know that gender. Try again\n")      
        elif gender != "female":
            gender = input("I do not know that gender. Try again \n")
        return
```

Output

```
Enter your gender 
    male
    I do not know that gender. Try again
    male
    How excellent! Are you a CS Major?
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Any guidance will help.

Comment: I think you mean `and`

Comment: `if(gender != "male" and gender != "female"):` or `if !(gender == "male" or gender == "female"):`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason your first code doesn't work is because `or` would still make it get in to the loop even if it's `male`, because `gender != 'male'` would give `False`, but `gender != 'female'` would give `True`.

Whereas:

```
>>> False or True
True
>>>
```

So you would need and:

```
def init_greeating(self):
    gender = input("Enter your gender\n")
    gender = gender.lower()
    if gender != "male" and gender != "female":
        gender = input("I do not know that gender. Try again ")
    return
```

It's the same case for example 2. The `elif` will still run because `gender == 'male'`.

So try this for the second example:

```
def init_greeating(self):
    gender = input("Enter your gender\n")
    gender = gender.lower()  

    if gender == "male":
        return      
    elif gender == "female":
        return
    gender = input("I do not know that gender. Try again\n")
```

Answer (score 2):

In your first method, you have 2 boolean statements in one. The first checks if it's not male, and the second checks if it's not female. If **either** are true, then it'll say it doesn't understand that gender. So, if you inputted `male`, then it would say that `not male` is false, but `not female` is true, meaning it'll say it doesn't know your gender.

In your second method, the same applies. It'll skip the first if statement because it knows for sure that `not male` is false, but it'll pass the elif statement because it knows that `not female` is true, so it'll say it doesn't know your gender.

As such, instead of checking for what the gender ISN'T, check for what it IS, then use an `else` statement for "I don't understand that gender."